# SVG Continuous Line Loader Animation

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations

I have the following SVG line:

```css
svg#line_loader {
 position: relative; float: left; clear: none; display: block;
 width: 100%; height: 8px; margin: 0; padding: 0;
 stroke: rgb(255, 205, 0);
 
 stroke-width: 10; stroke-linecap: round;

 stroke-dasharray: 100;
 stroke-dashoffset: 0;
 
 animation: dash 1s linear forwards infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
  0%   { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
  100%   { stroke-dashoffset: 100; }
}
```

```html
<svg id="line_loader"><line x1="100%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="0%"></line></svg>
```

However the animation ends up looking jagged.

**Take a look at: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/16hf27cq/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need each iteration to end in the same start position. This means that the offset should be `100%`, and the dashes should be a percentage of the containers width:

```css
svg#line_loader {
 position: relative; clear: none; display: block;
 width: 100%; height: 8px; margin: 0; padding: 0;
 stroke: rgb(255, 205, 0);
 
 stroke-width: 10; stroke-linecap: round;

 stroke-dasharray: 25%;
 
  animation: dash 1s linear forwards infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
  0%   { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
  100%   { stroke-dashoffset: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<svg id="line_loader"><line x1="100%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="0%"></line></svg>
```

Comment: If I change the size to 30% it's jagged again. With offset 0 and 100. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that some percentages work fine (10%, 25%, 50%), while other produce a jagged animation.